# Building a simple web form that connects to Recurly's API to allow a subscriber to change their subscription plan

Tags: rest, post, basic-authentication, recurly

I am trying to build a simple web form that would ideally sit on a WordPress page to allow the subscribers on our platform to change or update their subscriptions, without having to ask our support team (currently they can only cancel, but we want to offer them the option to upgrade).

We use Recurly to manage our billing, and their support team said:

'You would essentially want to build a form that will input values into the Subscription Update API request, that would then be sent to Recurly to make the changes on your customer account.'

They also shared the following document: https://dev.recurly.com/docs/update-subscription

I have limited experience of working with APIs and am also aware that because this form deals with sensitive information (the user ID of a subscriber in this case), I don't want to inadvertently jeopardise the accounts of the subscribers that choose to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried searching for a solution but am unsure how to word my request effectively.

Comment: In order to do this securely from a web form, you're going to need to write code that runs on the server. It's unclear to me whether you have access to that. It would be technically possible to do it all on the client side, but not without exposing your Recurly API key to the world -- and that's bad! If you do have the ability to run server-side code, let me know and I'll provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like using the Recurly Hosted UI might be your best bet. Instead of having to build a a web form you can just redirect your customer to the Recurly Hosted UI on a button click. You can retrieve and redirect the url using the Recurly API on your Wordpress site using some simple PHP and then that allows the customer to view invoices, change their plan (if you allow), and change CC information.